# Show WooCommerce products only to multiple authorized user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, user-roles

I'm trying to adapt *"[Completely hide products from unauthorized users in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56314804/completely-hide-products-from-unauthorized-users-in-woocommerce)"* answer code to also allow several custom user roles to view this products. I believe the best way to accomplish this is to expand the authorized user function to include this user roles.

This is the changes that I have tried to implement with no success. Can someone shine a light on how to proceed?

```
// Conditional function checking for authorized users

function is_authorized_user() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $caps = $user->allcaps;

        if ( ( isset($caps['edit_product']) && $caps['edit_product'] ) ||
        array( 'custom_user_role1', 'custom_user_role2', $user->roles ) )
           return true;
    } else 
        return false;
}
```

How to make it work for an array of user roles, instead of just one? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have 2 arrays to compare:

- your 2 custom roles (in an array)
- the current user roles (that is an array)

you can use [`array_intersect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) php function to make it work this way:

```
// Conditional function checking for authorized users
function is_authorized_user(){

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $caps = $user->allcaps;

        if ( ( isset($caps['edit_product']) && $caps['edit_product'] ) || 
        array_intersect( ['custom_user_role1', 'custom_user_role2'], $user->roles ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false; 
    } 
    else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

It should work now for multiple user roles.

Comment: Merci, ça marche nickel! Thank you LoicTheAztec this works exactly as needed.